# Problem on Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with Poisson distribution

$$ p_X(k) = e^{-\lambda} . \lambda^k / k!$$  for $k=0,1,2,... $

If it's given that

$$p_X(i) = p_X(j) \tag {*} $$

for some different integers $i < j$,

can we prove that

(1) $\lambda$ is also an integer
(2) $i=\lambda-1$ and $j=\lambda$ are the only two indexes with the (*) property

I am reading some proof but it's very short and not very convincing at 1-2 points.
So I wanted to check with the community here.

**UPDATE:**
The proof which I have first obtains that:
$\lambda^k = (i+1)(i+2)...(i+k)$
where $k=j-i$. This is easy to obtain from (*).
So far so good.

Then from there on it says:
"But this is only possible if k=1 (can you guess why?)"

Btw, I cannot guess why, not right now.

And from $k=1$ of course it follows trivially that
$i+1 = \lambda$
which means that
$j= \lambda$ and $i = \lambda-1$

So that's all I have in my hands. This sketch of a proof.

Comment: "it's very short" A good oint, right? "and not very convincing at 1-2 points" Which ones? Unless you tell us them, how can we help?

Comment: What is short? I don't understand... the proof? It is not long indeed but if I have to rewrite it with MathJax, it will take me ages, I am not very good with MathJax. I just don't understand if "$\lambda$ is integer" can be inferred from what is given or if it has to be given too. This is my ask basically.

Comment: Btw, the problem is very interesting (at least for me). I am not sure why somebody downvoted.

Comment: @Did I added some info. That's really all I have.

Comment: OK. This sounds like a bad MSE answer... Is this it? Then you could as well add a link to it...

Comment: No bad MSE answer. I am just reading a book, trying to solve some problems and to follow all the ideas, it's not even in English. And I have noone to ask really when issues arise. The book is actually a container of problems and a manual to help its readers in solving the problems, and that's why the proofs are so short and cryptic sometimes. It's a great book otherwise, 777 interesting problems. But there're some mistakes (at least in the Bulgarian text). Here is a link: this is the English version of the book, I have the Bulgarian original. https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789027726872

Comment: The Bulgarian edition is newer, the English text seems even older btw. Even the typesetting in the English text is ancient.

Comment: This is problem 9.16 in the book.

Comment: The book pretends that the fact there exists no integers $(i,j,k)$ such that $1\leqslant j\leqslant k$ and $$(i+j)^k=(i+1)(i+2)\cdots(i+k)$$ except if $k=1$, is obvious. It is not. Thus, what we have here are lazy, misleading, authors.

Comment: They stated that $\lambda$ is integer, it seems. I mean this was given. If it's given how is the other statement obvious?  `"But this is only possible if k=1 (can you guess why?)"`  Not that I care really already. We can just look at the Poisson distribution, analyze it more deeply (this is what I did in the last 2-3 days)... and all this follows from there. It's actually related to the fact that if $\lambda$ is integer then the Poisson distribution has 2 most probable values, otherwise it has just 1. That's all. It's just described in a pretty cryptic way.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I just found that we cannot infer (from what is given) that $\lambda$ is an integer. So this should be given. But if it's given then... What is this all about? Isn't it all too easy?
I just constructed a counter example:
If $\lambda = \sqrt{6}$ then $P_X(1) = P_X(3)$, right?
I am really confused what this problem is about. 
It is badly stated and badly proved. No idea. 
That's why I asked my question, I was hoping someone would have an idea what this is all about.